# Using Multiple HTML Tables with POST requests

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

This is probably a fairly easy question, I'm just not well-versed in either Rails or HTML...

I have two HTML tables in my View, both are being updated from their respective database table. I have a dropdown menu to select a time range for each table. I had originally used a GET request, but this messed up the other table, and I'd rather not have the params in the URL. So using POST, each table works independently, but each time I update one, it returns the other to its default time range, as specified by my `:selected =>` tag.

```
<%= form_tag home_landing_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag :timePeriod, options_for_select(["1 Week Ago", "3 Months Ago"], :selected => params[:timePeriod]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Refresh", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Both tables use identical code (with the exception of the `:timePeriod` param).
How do I get each table to "remember" where it was?

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, SQLite3 3.6.20

Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of the table that you're trying to update? It looks from your form like it's `home_landing_path`, but that seems to me like a weird name for a table. Did you use `rails generate scaffolding` to generate CRUD for this table?

Comment: @JasonSwett: I'm just trying to update the html table, using data from two sqlite tables called `events` and `apps`. I created the `home/landing` path using the `routes.rb` file. So no, I didn't create any scaffolds, I just created a controller, model, and view by hand.

Comment: So is the form supposed to affect both tables? How was the other table messed up by submitting the form?

Comment: @TomL: No, each form is only supposed to affect its respective table. So I can have one table displaying the past two week's data, while the other displays the past month's. Each table is currently defaulted to "1 Week Ago" upon loading the page. If I change the first table to "1 Month Ago", it works. Then, if I change the other table to "1 Month Ago", the first table returns to "1 Week Ago". I'd like each table to "remember" its current time period.

Comment: Sounds like a job for AJAX. Look at this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Hi @XMLSlayer - did you solve your problem? if so - please consider writing up the answer here to help others with the same problem. If my answer was helpful - also please upvote or "accept" it (you can accept by hovering your mouse to the left of the up/down buttons and clicking the green tick). Upvoting and accepting answers will make it more likely that people will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In html, forms are completely independent of one another.

If you submit one form (that surrounds just one table), then only the parameters that are in that form will arrive at the server. It gets none of the values from the other form... so when it re-renders the page, it doesn't know there ever were other values in the second form.

As with any problem, there are multiple ways of solving it each with their own issues.

AJAX is a good solution - it means that the form gets submitted, but you still stay on the page, with the original second-form still in place... that way all the info in the second form doesn't get lost every time you hit "submit".

If you can't do that for some reason, another (rather ugly) way would be to have just one form... posting to just one action... which then decides what to do based on whether there's useful information in form1 or form2's data. I don't recommend that way unless you must for some weird reason.

I'd say go for the AJAX method.